# Help in this proof of the argument principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 123 he made the following comment:

> Suppose that $f$ is analytic and has a zero of order $m$ at $z=a$. So
>   $f(z)=(z-a)^mg(z)$ where $g(a)\neq 0$. Hence
>
> **(3.1)** $$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{m}{z-a}+\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$$
>
> and $g'/g$ is analytic near $z=a$ since $g(a)\neq 0$. Now suppose that
>   $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z=a$; that is, $f(z)=(z-a)^{-m}g(z)$
>   where $g$ is analytic and $g(a)\neq 0$. This gives
>
> **(3.2)** $$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{-m}{z-a}+\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$$

Afterwards in order to prove the argument principle he said that we can get the following equality from (3.1) and (3.2):

[image]

So, why can we get

> $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{z-a_k}}-\sum_{j=1}^m{\frac{1}{z-p_j}}$$

from (3.1) and (3.2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(z)=\frac {(z-z_1)\dots(z-z_n)}{(z-p_1)\dots (z-p_m)}g(z)$$
And $g$ has no zero and no pole since $z_i$ and $p_i$ are all the zeros and poles of $f$.

Let's start, we let $a_1(z)=\frac {(z-z_2)\dots(z-z_n)}{(z-p_1)\dots (z-p_m)}g(z)$ : $$f(z)=(z-z_1)a_1(z) \Rightarrow \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac {1}{z-z_1}+\frac{a_1'(z)}{a_1(z)}$$
Let $a_2(z)=\frac {(z-z_3)\dots(z-z_n)}{(z-p_1)\dots (z-p_m)}g(z)$ :$$a_1(z)=(z-z_2)a_2(z) \Rightarrow \frac{a_1'(z)}{a_1(z)}=\frac {1}{z-z_2}+\frac{a_2'(z)}{a_2(z)} \Rightarrow \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac {1}{z-z_1}+\frac {1}{z-z_2}+\frac{a_2'(z)}{a_2(z)}$$
So by induction :
$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{z-z_k}}+\frac{a_{n-1}(z)}{a_{n-1}(z)}$$ Where $a_{n-1}(z)=\frac {1}{(z-p_1)\dots (z-p_m)}g(z)$.

Let $b_1(z)=\frac{1}{(z-p_2)\dots(z-p_m)}g(z)$
$$u(z)=\frac{1}{z-p_1}b_1 \Rightarrow \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{z-z_k}}-\frac{1}{z-p_1}+\frac{b_1'(z)}{b_1(z)}$$ 
We notice that $b_{m-1}=g(z)$, so by induction $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{z-z_k}}-\sum_{j=1}^m{\frac{1}{z-p_j}}+\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$$

Comment: maybe $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = (\ln f(z))'$  would be more direct

Comment: But OP wanted to prove this result by application of (3.1) and (3.2)

Comment: note that Conway didn't forbid using $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} =(\log f(z))'$ in each induction step :)

Comment: @user1952009 $\log f(z)$ isn't defined yet.

Comment: @user42912 : of course it is defined. one of the 1st theorem is : "if $h(z)$ is analytic/holomorphic on $|z-a| < C$ and $g(z)$ is analytic/holomorphic on $|z-b| < D$ with $|g(z)-a| < C$ then $h(g(z))$ is analytic on $|z-a| < C$"

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly I was looking for.

Comment: @user1952009 ok, but the author is _about_ to define it. He didn't define yet

Comment: @user42912 : you don't understand. I'm not talking of $\log f(z)$ on the whole complex plane but only on a small disk. yes defining $\log f(z)$ for every $z$ is complicated

Comment: It's not a big deal, it's just a remark. Maybe I'm wrong, but I found some minor typos in your answer.

Comment: @user1952009 yes, I understand that. He made this discussion just after this proof. See the page 124 of his book.

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not saying you can't use $\log f(z)$ to prove this theorem. I'm only saying that this answer fits better to my needs because I didn't study yet $\log f(z)$ ;)

Comment: @user42912 : anyway the point of the argument principle is to study $\log f(z)$, so you'll do it. and note how the fact that $f(z)$ is meromorphic (having no essential singularity) is very important for the argument principle

Comment: @user1952009 yes. I'm reading this right now. Thank you for your interesting remarks and comments. You're right, it seems simpler to prove this theorem using $\log f(x)$. If you want to share your thoughts in an answer, it would be nice ;)

Comment: @Bérénice thank you for great explanation. shouldn't it be derivative of a_n−1(z) in the numerator for last term on line 9 after "so by induction:"?

Comment: @Bérénice also there is a typo. instead of u(z) it should be f(z)

Comment: @Bérénice shouldn't the term a_n−1(z) be (z-z_1)...(z-z_m)g(z)?